# Swift - Protocol Delegate from TableView not working - Present Modally

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have one view controller with a button that when clicked goes to a second view controller with a table view. The two scenes are linked through storyboard, as Present Modally. I want the text of the button in the first view controller to change when a row is selected in the table view of the second view controller.

Is there a reason why the button is not changing when the cell is selected?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm still a beginner with Swift.

Below are the relevant lines of code:

View Controller 1

```
class ChartsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleButton: UIButton!

}

extension ChartsViewController: ModalDelegate {

    func didSelectValue(value: String) {
        self.titleButton.setTitle(value, for: .normal)
        }
}
```

View Controller 2

```
protocol ModalDelegate: class {
    func didSelectValue(value: String)
}

class DashboardModalViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ModalDelegate?
}

extension DashboardModalViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let rowTitle = self.rows[indexPath.row].text
        print (rowTitle)
        delegate?.didSelectValue(value: rowTitle)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing the delegate as self when presenting the modal VC?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure what that means, so I would say I haven't done that yet.

Comment: Please show your `prepare(for segue:)` method, If didn't implement this method then implement as suggested by Yun CHEN.

Comment: Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the second controller's delegate in View Controller 1's `prepare` method for segue like:

```
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let dashboardModalViewController = segue.destination as? DashboardModalViewController {
        dashboardModalViewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you would set the second view controller's delegate to the first view controller?

Comment: Second view controller will call back to the first one to pass the value. So the second one need to know whom to be called.